# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Razer Blade Stealth 2020

Tags: boot, grub2

Device: Razer blade stealth 13" 2020

Specifications:

- I7 1065G7
- NVIDIA GTX 1650 TI
- 16Gb ram
- 512Gb Nvme SSD
- 13" 1920*1080 @ 120hz

Ubuntu distribution: Latest Ubuntu 20.04 directly downloaded from Ubuntu.

Problems:
Booting from USB works when adding 'nomodeset' to the params, installing Ubuntu works when permanently changing the parameters to include nomodeset, when installing NVIDIA drivers the laptop still boots but fails to render properly and only shows artifacts.

Tried kernel 5.7 with the latest NVIDIA and recommended NVIDIA drivers
Tried kernel 5.4(the default one) with the latest NVIDIA and recommended NVIDIA drivers.

All resulting in artifacts when attempting to boot the laptop.

Note: The laptop itself functions perfectly fine. (Tried in windows)

Any help is welcome

UPDATE: I found this issue and this managed to install the GPU drivers

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-nvidia-gpu-screens-are-not-yet-supported/120834/4